# ul tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in a .NET application. I'm trying to use jQuery to hide the children of the ul tags, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade row" id="FACSLinks">
    <br />
    <ul id="facslinks1" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-12">
        <li>
            <a href="#">FACS UWay Online Auction</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">FAX Transmission Reports</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Volunteer Drive Schedule</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Taxi Requests</a>
        </li>
        <li>  
            <a href="#">Tech Trouble Tickets</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Here are the scripts I have tried:

```
$("#facslinks1").hide();

$("#facslinks1 li").hide();

$("#facslinks1 li a").hide();
```

None of the scripts work. Just don't want to keep focusing on this if its something that bootstrap interferes with. But if it's just the fact I am doing it completely wrong, just let me know.

Comment: Just to check, you are calling these functions after the DOM has loaded, right?

Comment: Make sure your div is closed

Comment: div is closed and DOM is loading

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/4937t/55/

Comment: Are you certain you load jQuery?

Comment: Errors in the console?

Comment: using newer jQuery, and have older java installed on the computer

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is  with load. Try using ready instead, it would work. like below code

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#facslinks").hide();
});

</script>
```

or

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#facslinks li").hide();
});

</script>
```

or

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#facslinks li a").hide();
});

</script>
```

all will work now.

Comment: It doesn't though. :/ The only code that will work is when I set a timeout setTimeout(function... etc.

Comment: @JoshBarber - Please setup your own fiddle for us that shows the problem you're having, since none of us can reproduce it.

Comment: i don't think its jQuery related then.

Comment: just because all this code works in fiddle, but won't work in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `fade` class for the demo, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nZdF6/1/) is a fiddle of your code that works fine.  As the commenter mentioned, you do have to make sure the dom is loaded before using `jQuery`

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: the weird thing is this works. Why would this work:    

setTimeout(function () {
        $("#facslinks1").hide();
    }, 1000);

whereas this wouldn't:

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#facslinks1).hide();
});

Comment: @JoshBarber - Remove the setTimeout from the fiddle and it still works.

Comment: yeah. It works in fiddle, but won't work in my application. It seems only the setTimeout function only works.

Comment: I don't understand why that would only work though :/

Comment: If setTimeout works but doc.ready doesn't in your app, you have some kind of initialization problems.  Are you using any client side templating?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the code on doc ready like this:

```
$(function(){
     $('#facslinks1').find('li').hide();
});
```

Comment: Must be something else, try opening debugger window (f12) and looking for an error. I forked a previous fiddle showing document ready code working: http://jsfiddle.net/adamfullen/JV3bH/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an older java script on the computer and was trying to use a newer version of jQuery.